# C++ transform and lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, map-function

Is it possible to turn this into simple and nice usage of `std::transform`?

```
int j = 0;
for (auto &vi : V)
{
    auto div_res = div(vi + j, 10);
    j = div_res.quot;
    vi = div_res.rem;
}
```

This code does a very simple thing and it *feels* that is should be much shorter and clearer.

Or, if not transform, is there any std function that makes this sort of things easier?

Comment: Why didn't you [try yourself](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) ?

Comment: Your code is simple and elegant!!!

Comment: Your algorithm looks like a combination of `accumulate` and `transform`. I don't think there's a generic algorithm in the Standard Library that can be used to reproduce/simplify your algorithm in an elegant way.

Comment: @dyp One can probably use a functor with internal state to encapsulate `j`, but imo the code above is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
std::transform(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vi.begin(), 
    [&j](auto elem) /* or const auto& elem */
    {
        auto div_res = div(elem + j, 10);
        j = div_res.quot;
        return div_res.rem;
    }
);
```

However in this case a range-based `for` is probably as good (if not better) than `std::transform`.